# SignalR or Redis pubsub for scaled publishers and scaled subscribers on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, notifications, redis, signalr

In our application there is a event emitter (window service A) that emits events on queue. There is a notification service (B) (window service hosted in cloud) that reads these events from queue and based on configured rules, send notifications to loggedin users on web application (C).

We are planning to use signalR between web browser and the web application (C). But confused on setting communication between event emitter (A) and Notification service (B). Initially we are thinking to use SignalR there as well. But there is a catch. If load increases, notification service and web app can scale out (having more than one instance).

Lets say there are 3 notification service instances and 4 webserver instances. Now, how would SignalR works between them. Each web server has to open a signalR channel with every notification engine. But this would lead to issue:

There will be tight coupling between notification service and web application. Whenever a new web instance is added, it has to form connection all available notification instance. And it goes down it has to destroy this connection. Same hold true with notification instance.

So, we are thinking of using some pubsub rather than signalR. Right now we can think of Redis pubsub. Notification services will push message to Redis and all the web servers will be subscribing to it and will eventually get message.

Please share your thoughts if we can design it better.

Answer (score 1):

Redis *pubsub* isn't a reliable messaging system. It's *fire and forget*. If some message is sent to some channel and there's no listener, the message is lost.

If you're already in Azure, your solution is [*Service Bus*](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/service-bus/) and take a look at [topics and brokered messages](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions/).

Comment: Thanks Matias for your response,

Comment: Thanks Matias for your response, Problem is, there are two kind of listeners for this service. One, that process messages one after other and need reliable messaging system. This component listens to all the messages. We can use Service bus in this case. But in case of web-application, we need dynamic listener. For example if two users ares logged in and they land on a dashboard for item1 and item2, web application will only subscribed for these two kind of messages. And once user logged out, it will unsubscribed for them. Should I use 'Service Bus' as well as 'Redis pub sub'?

Comment: @Pragmatic Why not? At the end of the day, each kind of message should be a *topic*.

Comment: Azure topic is fine and can be created, but creating/deleting subscription dynamically can be time consuming. I mean, there can be 10000 different kind of products. And any user can be viewing any product. Now he should be subscribed to messages related to that product only.  Creating/deleting so many subscriptions does not look good.

Comment: @Pragmatic Well, but I was thinking about a subscription to a product topic and a worker role can be the subscriber to the product topic. Then, the messages, for example in JSON format, may contain a product kind, id or whatever info you might need